# Не понимаю как читать зашифрованные письма

Tags: linux, шифрование, email

У меня есть 2 почтовых аккаунта - один на `protonmail.com`, второй на `onionmail.org`. Когда я отправляю письмо с Proton на Onion, оно шифруется и я не могу его прочесть (в другую сторону всё работает). К Onion у меня подключён почтовый клиент Claws. Я пробовал установить на него все доступные плагины, связанные с шифрованием, но это не помогло. Вот как выглядит полученное зашифрованое письмо:

[image: письмо]

Я получаю зашифрованное сообщение и ключ, но похоже что клиент не знает что делать с этим ключём. Я могу сохранить и открыть его текстовым редактором, он называется **encrypted.asc** и содержит примерно следующее:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: ProtonMail

wV4DfCvuJWDZJs4SAQdAhyINmPauQ5GvZTEXF0/KIJVhTLCICkpCKdecV1VG
...
e8NXFGvojsPB8EiI7z/6dbB/qSrRTn4Be+JLbqN3b5jTfp3SNb0=
=W0Fn
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Я пробовал импортировать ключ командой `gpg --import encrypted.asc` и получит ответ: `no valid OpenPGP data found`. Что ещё тут можно попробвать, даже не знаю.

**UDP**: Моя главная проблема решена!

Теперь я могу читать письма в обе стороны. Для этого мне пришлось на сайте Proton зайти в раздел "Контакты", там выбрать свою Onion-почту, нажать на значёк шестерёнок и удалить прикреплённый ключ шифрования.

Теперь переписка осуществляется с простым шифрованием, без дополнительных ключей. Однако я совсем не разбираюсь в данной теме, по этому моё решение вряд ли можно назвать ответом на вопрос. Я не знаю как мне снова начать зашифрованную переписку и не уверен что при обмене ключами в будущем всё будет гладко (возможно что и будет, потому что в момент первого обмена ключами у меня не были установлены gpg-плагины в почтовом клиенте). В целом мне это шифрование ни к чему. Я интересуюсь только на случай если получу от кого-то важное письмо и не смогу расшифровать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для шифрованной переписки нужно 2 пары PGP ключей. На оба почтовых ящика сгенерируй пару публичных и приватных ключей. Приватный ключ устанавливается в почтовом клиенте в настройках, а публичный передается адресату.

Ключи установить и сделать можно программой Seahorse. Если почтовая программа поддерживает gpg - она увидит приватный ключ. Если не увидит - экспортируй его и импортируй в настройки программы.

Программа Claws говорит Вам что в ней не установлен приватный ключ, который шел в паре с публичным который был установлен в Протонмайле.